# How to make new page in html?

Tags: html

I am a noob at HTML.
I have a folder on my desktop with page1.html and page2.html.
This is an example of page1

```
<html>
<h1> Welcome
<title>Website
</h1>
<body>
<p> to page 2
</body>
<a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link</a>
</html>
```

Whenever I open page1.html, It just says "Welcome", and "to page 2". There is no hyperlink. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `</p>` tag and the `<a>` tag should be inside the `<body>` tag.

`<h1>` tag is malformed as well. Remember, this is just like parentheses in math. If you open one then you need to close one.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>
<a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link to page 2</a>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The A tag should be inside the body tags. You probably also want to close the p tag.

Try something like:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Website</title></head>
  <body>
     <h1>Welcome</h1>
     <p>to page 2 <a href="page2.html">Link</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (remember to close your tags!)

```
<html>
<h1> Welcome 
<title>Website </title>
</h1>
<body>
<p> to page 2 </p>
<a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should close `<title>` with `</title>`. Fixing that will make the rest of the content show ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVeWt/)).

As others are saying, you should also close your `<p>` tags, and move the `<a>` inside the `<body>`. Also, `<title>Welcome</title>` should be outside `<h1>`, and `<h1>` should be inside `<body>`.

It simpler to see with an example. The valid HTML would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>to page 2</p>
    <a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[See the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hYrP/).

Comment: Thanks, all of these awnsers generally say the same thing but this is most descriptive. I understand it a lot better now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `<title>` tag should go in your document's head and your content should all be inside the body. You also need to close all your tags.

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p> To page 2: <a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The title and everything the browser needs to understand the page is better suited to go in between the `<head> </head>` tags.

The content that has to be displayed in the browser viewport windows has to be in between the `<body> </body>` tags.  As others have mentioned, most of the HTML tags require to be closed.

Also, the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document before the `<html>` tag.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>            
        <head>
          <title>Website</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <h1> Welcome </h1>
          <p> to page 2 </p>
          <a href="page2.html" target="_self">Link</a>
        </body>            
    </html>
```

For a quick tutorial or help you can always refer the following website seen below. It's easy and fun. Best of luck!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp